# passing  parameter as   to  webservcie  function  in wcf

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

this my datagrid event  here i am calling the webservice.

```
    private void dgProject_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
    {
WSDataServiceClient wsService = new WSDataServiceClient();

 wsService.GetProjectCompleted += new EventHandler<GetProjectCompletedEventArgs>(wsService_GetProjectCompleted);
                        wsService.GetProjectAsync(strUniqueName);
```

// here can i send  datagrid as  an parameter to the  function?
 Datagrid gd= new Datagrid();
}

```
 void wsService_GetProjectCompleted(object sender, GetProjectCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
//

 }
```

is there  any way that i can send datagrid as a paramter to this  function is it possiable  to do?
 beacuse i will be using the same  websevice function her but need  to bind result with different datagrid based on the  condition if i can send a datagrid as  paramter to this  function  i can reduce the  code  so

any help on this issue  would be great 
 thank  you.

Comment: A datagrid is a UI component that visualizes data - why do you want to send the grid to the webservice?? You should send the underlying data that is being shown - not the grid itself!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to pass a reference a datagrid and when web service call is completed you want to populate that grid with the data. If you insist to to use the same function you probably can make the call of the async function that way:

> wsService.GetProjectAsync(strUniqueName,yourDataGrid);

and when the call is completed you can access that grid:

> void
>   wsService_GetProjectCompleted(object
>   sender, GetProjectCompletedEventArgs
>   e)  {
>       DataGrid grid = e.UserState as DataGrid;
>       //your code here  }

I hope this helps.